# how to implement the OnTouchListener ?

Tags: android, surfaceview, ontouchlistener

I am trying to implements the OnTouchListener but I keep getting the following error: 
     Multiple markers at this line
    - OnTouchListener cannot be resolved 
     to a type
I have looked at other similar questions and their issues was concerned with Upper-case letter of the word OnTouchListener, I even tried to import android.view.View; but still I keep getting the same error.

```
   import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;


public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable, OnTouchListener{ //error 

    SurfaceHolder myHolder;
    Thread myThread;
    boolean isRunning=true;

    public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        myHolder = getHolder();
        myThread = new Thread(this);
        myThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(isRunning)
    {
    if(!myHolder.getSurface().isValid())
    continue;
    Canvas canvas = myHolder.lockCanvas();
    //////////////////////////////////////

    canvas.drawARGB(255, 150, 150, 10);
    //////////////////////////////////////
    myHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
    }
    public void stop()
    {
    isRunning=false;
    while(true)
    {
    try {
    myThread.join();
    break;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } // block until thread dies
    break;
    }
    }
    public void start()
    {
    isRunning=true;
    myThread = new Thread(this); // this it means it will use the run  method
    myThread.start();
    }
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 

    return true;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this import

```
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying back,